# Possible to hide a table's column without hiding the cells below the table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good Day,

Is it possible to hide a table's column without hiding the cells below the table?
A pop tart to the winner, I say.

Thanks,
Dwaine

Answer (score 1):

No.

As a workaround, you can insert a column, move that table's column to this new column, then hide the column for the entire worksheet.

... or move your table to its own worksheet.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you!